# Use OpenGL on MacOs Big Sur

Tags: macos, opengl, deprecated, macos-big-sur

Is it possible to use **OpenGL** on MacOs Big Sur?

I have a project to do for my studies and for that we have to use a library that uses OpenGL but when I try to compile the library it gets me full of OpenGl errors and tells me that it is **deprecated**.

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean "removed" or "unavailable"; that's why it's a different word. It simply means "to be removed in the future, so don't rely on it."

Comment: Adding on to what Nicol said, OpenGL is still present on MacOS, but it's not being maintained anymore. If I remember correctly, the highest version of the OpenGL API is 4.1 on Mac.

Comment: I thought it was because of OpenGl that my library was not working but actually it wasn't because of that.
Sorry for the useless post and thanks for the replies